# tomcat rest backend angular frontend postman

Tags: angular, rest, tomcat, postman

I have trouble consuming a tomcat POST service with an angular front end. I'm fairly new to Angular.
My environment

- tomcat 9.0
- jdk 17
- Angular 17 with standalone components
- javax.ws.rs framework
- Eclips 2023-06
- vs code 1.85.1

I have tried Postman and the service respond as expected.
The server side. I have breakpoints on both System.out... and return Response...
When I use postman i stop at both breakpoint. When use the angular frontend. I get nothing, even the eclipse console is blank. I was expecting som kind of out in form an exception, get nothing.

```
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Path("/tag/add")
    public Response addTag(AddTag tag) {
        System.out.println(tag);
        return Response.status(200).entity("new tag: " + tag).build();

    }
```

component.html

```
<div class="tagForm">
    <form [formGroup]="filterForm">
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Namn på ny tag</mat-label>
            <input type="text" matInput formControlName="tagName">
        </mat-form-field>
        <button mat-button (click)="addTag()">Lägg till</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

component.ts

```
  addTag() {
    let name = this.tagName?.value
    let tagName = <addTag>({
      name: name,
      id: this.imageId
    });

    console.log("addTag: " + tagName);
    this.photoalbumService.addTag(tagName);
  }
```

photoalbum.service.ts

```
  addTag(data: addTag): Observable<string> {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: ({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
    }
    let jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
    console.log(jsonData);
    const url = baseURL + "/tag/add";
    console.log("addTag, url: " + url);
    return this.httpClient.post<string>(url, jsonData, httpOptions);

  }
```

I get the baseURL from an environment(environment.dev.ts) file.

```
export const environment = {
    production: "dev",
    serverBaseUrl: "http://localhost:8080/photoalbumservice/rest/api",
    imageBaseUrl: "http://localhost:8080"
};
```

I have tried with postman, and that work.

```
http://localhost:8080/photoalbumservice/rest/api/tag/add
```

I send the following as body, raw.

```
{ "id": 123, "name":"kalle"}
```

The console log in vs code it ass following.

```
addTag: [object Object] tag.component.ts:69:12
{"name":"jhkl","id":413791} photoalbum.service.ts:73:12
addTag, url: http://localhost:8080/photoalbumservice/rest/api/tag/add photoalbum.service.ts:75:12
```

I pretty sure that I missed some info needed, so if you need more info I will do my best to supply.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to subscribe to the returned Observable when calling addTag().

```
this.photoalbumService.addTag(tagName).subscribe({
  next: value => console.log('Observable emitted the next value: ' + value),
  error: err => console.error('Observable emitted an error: ' + err),
  complete: () => console.log('Observable emitted the complete notification')
});
```